# Delete canceled meetings from resource calendar in Exchange 2003

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003, calendar, mailbox

I have an Exchange 2003 server that has accounts for rooms/resources set to autoaccept meeting requests.  When those meetings are canceled, however, the meeting remains in the resource's calendar as a canceled meeting.  This makes the calendar untidy and hard to use.

Is there any way to have meetings automatically deleted from the resource's calendar when it is canceled?

Failing that, is there a way to set up permissions so that people can manually remove canceled meetings, but not modify non-canceled ones?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the auto accept agent should handle these.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124617(EXCHG.65).aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996223(EXCHG.65).aspx

However, the person cancelling has to *send* notice of cancellation for this to work.

Comment: It sure does *say* that.  It doesn't seem to *do* that.  It just prepends "Canceled" to the meeting name.  I'll doublecheck that the auto accept agent isn't misconfigured somehow, though.